# Progress dialog in LibVLC Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, progressdialog, libvlc

In my application am showing live video streaming, for that i have used [LibVLC library](https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample/src). Everything is working properly.

Before playing video i want to show progress dialog, because until video gets start LibVLC surface(black screen) appears, because of which user might think video is not loading.

I tried to add progress dialog, which appears on video streaming start, but on LibVLC's `EventHandler.MediaPlayerPlaying` event I dismiss it assuming video gets started,but after this event for next 5-10 seconds video buffering is happening.

How can i derive that video buffering is completed so on that event i can dismiss progress dialog?

Comment: Hi have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use the media state from the player.
0 nothing,
1 opening,
2 buffering,
3 playing,
4 paused,
5 stopped,
6 ended,
7 error

```
    if not self.player.get_media():
        print "fail"
        return
    else:
        media_state = self.player.get_state()
        while media_state != 3 and media_state != 4:
            media_state = self.player.get_state()
            print repr(media_state)
    print repr(media_state)
```