# How to add loader with LibVLC in Android using its event handler?

Tags: android, live-streaming, libvlc

In my application i have used `LibVLC library` to show `live video streaming`. Everything is working fine; Only problem is it takes 8-10 seconds to buffer and play video, and during that period black screen appears which is `LibVLC`'s video surface. I want to show `Progress dialog` in this process.

I tried to add `Progress dialog` on `Activity` start and dismiss it on, `LibVLC'`s Playing event.

```
case EventHandler.MediaPlayerPlaying:
                    Log.e(TAG, "video is playing");

                    pd.dismiss();
```

But problem is, after Playing event, `LibVLC` starts buffering of video, which means after dismissing `Progress dialog` still for 5-6 seconds black screen appears.

So, I want know, If there is any method to detect `buffering`? or to show `progress dialog` till video gets started.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progress dialog in LibVLC Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868822/progress-dialog-in-libvlc-android)

Comment: @leviat No,its not duplicate, that question is also asked by me. In this question I am using Event Handler. In previous one Event handle not used.